# Fubini-Tonelli Theorem

Tags: measure-theory

I am not really understanding how to use the Fubini theorem properly. From my understanding, I think it means if $\int_{X} \int_{Y} |f(x,y)| dy dx < \infty$ OR $\int_{Y} \int_{X} |f(x,y)| dx dy < \infty$, then $\int_{X} \int_{Y} f(x,y) dy dx = \int_{Y} \int_{X} f(x,y) dx dy$. Also, I want to check my understanding of Tonelli's theorem. I believe it states that if $f(x,y) \geq 0 , \forall (x,y) \in X \times Y$, then $\int_{X} \int_{Y} f(x,y) dy dx = \int_{Y} \int_{X} f(x,y) dx dy$. I would like to know if my conception of these two theorems are correct, and if examples could be provided in which these theorems are applied, I would appreciate it.

Comment: your understanding is perfectly right. It can be added to Fubini-Tonelli also that if $\int_X\int_Y |f(x,y)| dxdy<\infty$ then $\int_X\int_Y |f(x,y)| dxdy=\int_{X\times Y} |f(x,y)|d(x,y)$

Comment: You're missing an important fact, the measure spaces should be complete $\sigma$- finite. Otherwise, the theorem fails.

Comment: Application of Tonelli's theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469304/application-of-lebesgue-differentiation-theorem

Comment: Fubini's theorem is a special case of Tonelli's theorem, where $f: X \times Y \to \mathbb{C}$ & $f \in L^1( \mathbb{ \mu \times \nu})$. So, it's really the Tonelli's theorem that does the heavy lifting.